# rails asset pipeline images and css not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am new to rails and am following the examples in Michael Hartl.  I am having an issue in chapter 5 (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout). I have followed the michaels instructions but I am not seeing images and my css is not displaying.
I am using ruby Rails 5.0.1 with ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

I added michaels html/code to my home.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Home") %>
<div class="center jumbotron">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

  <h2>
    This is the home page for the
    <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
  </h2>

  <%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>

<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"),
            'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>


<br/><br/>  

<%= link_to image_tag("bunratty.png", alt: "Bunratty"),
            'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
<%= link_to image_tag("kitten.png", alt: "Kitten"),
            'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
<%= image_tag image_url('rails.png') %>
<%= image_tag image_path('rails.png') %>
Display using html
<img src="/public/rails.png" alt="rails logo"/>
```

I copied the rails.png image into app/assets/images/ directory but when I run the application the image is not displayed only the alt tag is displayed.

I also added bootstrap as per the instructions and it isnt working either.

gemfile extract
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails',        '5.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'
```

---

I ran bundle install and can see it is installed using a bundle show
$ bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actioncable (5.0.1)
  * actionmailer (5.0.1)
  * actionpack (5.0.1)
  * actionview (5.0.1)
  * activejob (5.0.1)
  * activemodel (5.0.1)
  * activerecord (5.0.1)
  * activesupport (5.0.1)
  * ansi (1.5.0)
  * arel (7.1.4)
  * autoprefixer-rails (6.7.5)
  * bootstrap-sass (3.3.6)
  * builder (3.2.3)
  * bundler (1.13.7)
  * coderay (1.1.1)
  * coffee-rails (4.2.1)
  * coffee-script (2.4.1)
  * coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
  * concurrent-ruby (1.0.4)
  * debug_inspector (0.0.2)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (2.7.0)
  * ffi (1.9.17)
  * formatador (0.2.5)
  * globalid (0.3.7)
  * guard (2.13.0)
  * guard-compat (1.2.1)
  * guard-minitest (2.4.4)
  * i18n (0.8.0)
  * jbuilder (2.4.1)
  * jquery-rails (4.1.1)
  * listen (3.0.8)
  * loofah (2.0.3)
  * lumberjack (1.0.11)
  * mail (2.6.4)
  * method_source (0.8.2)
  * mime-types (3.1)
  * mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
  * mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
  * minitest (5.10.1)
  * minitest-reporters (1.1.9)
  * multi_json (1.12.1)
  * nenv (0.3.0)
  * nio4r (1.2.1)
  * nokogiri (1.7.0.1)
  * notiffany (0.1.1)
  * pg (0.18.4)
  * pry (0.10.4)
  * puma (3.4.0)
  * rack (2.0.1)
  * rack-test (0.6.3)
  * rails (5.0.1)
  * rails-controller-testing (0.1.1)
  * rails-dom-testing (2.0.2)
  * rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
  * railties (5.0.1)
  * rake (12.0.0)
  * rb-fsevent (0.9.8)
  * rb-inotify (0.9.8)
  * ruby-progressbar (1.8.1)
  * sass (3.4.23)
  * sass-rails (5.0.6)
  * shellany (0.0.1)
  * slop (3.6.0)
  * spring (1.7.2)
  * spring-watcher-listen (2.0.0)
  * sprockets (3.7.1)
  * sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.12)
  * thor (0.19.4)
  * thread_safe (0.3.5)
  * tilt (2.0.6)
  * turbolinks (5.0.1)
  * turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
  * tzinfo (1.2.2)
  * tzinfo-data (1.2016.10)
  * uglifier (3.0.0)
  * web-console (3.1.1)
  * websocket-driver (0.6.5)
  * websocket-extensions (0.1.2)

---

I added a custom.scss file to app\assets\stylesheets

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* universal */

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color:lime;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

---

Is this a problem with the assets pipeline since neither the css or images are displaying.
I have tried putting the image in the public directory, the public/images directory, the app/assets directory but it isn't display in any of these.
I have tried using a different image incase the image is corrupted
I have tried using creating a  new project

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Thank your for coming back to me.  Some extra information as requested:

I don't have an application.scss file, just an application.css file with the following content:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

The html generated is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/stylesheets/default.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
    <script src="/javascripts/default.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
    <title>Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial</title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="SogDGi5kvIl13JKu57VqH0phQ/1pSw+tKuVAmvTVuQITclDhVvKLJNwHJJzcOa0qUlOhJ8cmRsBx9rUCINA+TQ==" />
  </head>

  <body>

  <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <a id="logo" href="#">sample app</a>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="center jumbotron">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

  <h2>
    This is the home page for the
    <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
  </h2>

  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Sign up now!</a>
</div>

<a href="http://rubyonrails.org/"><img alt="Rails logo" src="/images/rails.png" /></a>


<br/><br/>  

<a href="http://rubyonrails.org/"><img alt="Bunratty" src="/images/bunratty.png" /></a>
<a href="http://rubyonrails.org/"><img alt="Kitten" src="/images/kitten.png" /></a>
<img src="http://localhost:3000/images/rails.png" alt="Rails" />
<img src="/images/rails.png" alt="Rails" />
Display using html
<img src="/public/rails.png" alt="rails logo"/>


<img src="/public/rails.png" alt="rails logo"/>

<img src="http://localhost:3000/public/rails.png" alt="rails logo"/>
<br/>
http://localhost:3000/images/rails.png

</div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Accessing localhost:3000/assets/rails.png in a browser gives the following error.

No route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png"
Rails.root: c:/rails/static_app

Comment: What's the generated html for the image? Also have you changed anything in development.rb or application.rb?

Comment: Can you include `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` to your post?

Comment: Also, put your images inside `app/assets/images` and try to access this url on your browser `http://localhost:3000/assets/rails.png`

Comment: Thanks, I have added more detail above as requested.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your action that generates the following views has a controller calling the layout `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` as shown on chapter 5, then you need to require your custom.scss on your application.scss

your controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout 'application'

  def index
  end

end
```

your application.scss

```
/*
  = require_self
*/
@import "custom.scss";
```

The index action is just an example, if you named your view home.html.erb I can imagine you are pointing to a `home` action inside your controller